# Compatibility between ubuntu and new MacBook Pro 15' with retina

Tags: macbook-pro

I've a problem with my new MacBook Pro 15' with retina,I need to install in a partition Linux to work. I had try to install ubuntu 13.10 and 14.04, anytime the installation was concluded successfully,but starting ubuntu nothing happens. 
So,I would know which ubuntu version I can install.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the 64bit Mac image. It is not listed on Ubuntu.com, but you can download it from here: http://releases.ubuntu.com/trusty/. That'll give you the 14.04Beta for Mac. If you want 13.10 instead, use http://releases.ubuntu.com/saucy/